# How do I retrieve a partial text from a website using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium with both firefox and chrome and I was wondering on how to be able to get a certain part of a text and only that part.

```
<div align="center">
Your PR application has been submitted sucessfully.
<br>
Application Number :PR_____
<br>
PR number : _____
</div>
```

what if I only want the second part of the text?

**Application Number :PR_____**

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: So you want **PR_____** ? If so you need to do that with whatever language with are using. Not with Selenium

Comment: I'm using java, I can get the whole text out but not individual lines which is really bugging me

Comment: You still haven't said which part you want. Just **Application Number :PR_____**? or **PR_____**?

Comment: Oh. I just want PR___ yes.

Comment: you can get the entire Text and split it on the basis of ":"  or use String contains method to verify the sub string.

Comment: Is there any simple examples? I'm not sure I follow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following and 2nd index should contain the text you want. With xpath it's quite impossible

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div")).getText();

String[] trimmedText = text.split(":");

for (String str : trimmedText) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

> Print
>
> Your PR application has been submitted sucessfully.
>
> Application Number
>
> PR_____
>
> PR number
>
> ---

Comment: Really helpful but I need to further narrow it down, I tried getting the second index but it gave me PR___ (which is what I wanted) along with PR number,

is there a way to make the latter go away?

Comment: Yes, do it `String[] trimmedText = text.split(":PR");` instead of `String[] trimmedText = text.split(":");`